# CUDA IPC Ops Not Supported On Windows? Is there a workaround?

Tags: pytorch

When trying to train a neural network with a custom DataLoader:

```
train_dataset = datasets.VectorizedDataset(x_train,y_train)
train_loader = datasets.DataLoader(shuffle=True,num_workers=4)
```

This immediately errors out on data loading with:

```
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (71) : operation not supported at c:\a\w\1\s\tmp_conda_3.6_090826\conda\conda-bld\pytorch_1550394668685\work\torch\csrc\generic\StorageSharing.cpp:232
```

And this (CUDA IPC ops) is documented [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html):

> They are not supported on Windows. Something like doing
>   multiprocessing on CUDA tensors cannot succeed, there are two
>   alternatives for this.
>
> 1. Don’t use multiprocessing. Set the num_worker of DataLoader to zero.
> 2. Share CPU tensors instead. Make sure your custom DataSet returns CPU tensors.

I'm using a GTX 1070 GPU on **Windows 10** via PyTorch 1.0.1 and CUDA 10.0.

Is it literally not possible to offload CUDA tensor data loading to multiple CPUs on Windows machines in Pytorch? Is there a workaround? Do we have to do something more complicated like write our own multithreading? Or are we forced to keep all data loading on the main process?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm wondering that too